# Notice : Undefined index: Suma de array dentro de un for each

Tags: php

Hola buen día estoy tratando de corregir esa notice y no logró solucionarlo, les pido que por favor me brinden de su experiencia,la noticie que me aparece es la siguiente Notice : Undefined index:2020-1 lo que hice fue aplicar un foreach para sumar las compras que tengo en un array que contiene la fecha y el valor de la compra con un var_dump se ve así:

```
array(1) { ["2020-1"]=> string(3) "250" } array(1) { ["2020-1"]=> string(3) "700" }
```

Y le aplique un foreach a ese arrayCompras y luego dentro de otro array  $sumaComprasMes[$key] asigne la suma de cada valor es decir, que sumaComprasMes[de el mes asignado en ese momento] es igual a la suma de todo lo que se compro en ese mes.

```
foreach ($arrayCompras as $key => $value) {
        $sumaCompras[$key] += $value;
        }
```

El resultado que me arroja es prefecto me hace el calculo de las compras de cada mes pero me aparece el noticie que está arriba, por lo cual no se que estoy haciendo mal. De ante mano muchas gracias por el apoyo.

Comment: Coloca una muestra de tu *array* para poder reproducir tu escenario

Comment: Hola amigo el array lo declaro así arriba esta el ejemplo de como se ve cuando le aplico un var_dump foreach ($respuesta as $key => $value) {
 //Capturamos sólo el año y el mes
 $fecha = substr($value["fecha_venta"],0,7);
 //Capturamos el total de las compras
 $arrayCompras = array($fecha => $value["total"]);

Comment: se ve que los dos array no tienen la misma cantidad de items o las mismas key...

Comment: Si si tienen la misma cantidad de item y de key de echo me hace los calculos necesarios a la perfección

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que no estás creando los índices necesarios para `$sumaCompras`

```
// Define primero el array para hacer las sumas
$sumaCompras = [];
foreach ($arrayCompras as $key => $value) {
    // Verifica que existe el índice:
    if(!isset($sumaCompras[$key])) {
        // No existe, lo creas e inicializas en cero
        $sumaCompras[$key] = 0;
    }
    // Listo, ya puedes sumar sin problemas
    $sumaCompras[$key] += $value;
}
```

Comment: Si esta es la respuesta correcta, muchísimas gracias que Dios le pague y le bendiga.